# Tomcat does not read link as parameter

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, tomcat7

I am using Jersey/java to create a web service that runs on tomca7.
When I pass a URL as a parameter in the @PathParam it does not display anything, but when it is a regular string it works fine.
Here is a modified demo of what I am doing..

For example if I put:

```
localhost/app/.../broaders/test
```

it will display: `test`

But if i put:

```
localhost/app/.../broaders/http%3A%2F%2Ftematres.befdata.biow.uni-leipzig.de%2Fvocab%2F%3Ftema%3D254
```

or even just

```
localhost/app/..../broaders/http%3A2F2F
```

it does not display anything.

```
@GET
@Path("broaders/{k}")
@produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@public String getBroader(@PathParam("k") String k){
    return k;
 }
```

I added the -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true to Catalina.proprieties but without luck.

Comment: "When I pass a URL as a parameter in the @PathParam" What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that in the browser URL if i write PATH/broaders/string, it displays the string, but when I type a link with "/" or "%2F" it does not display anything!

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample URLs that work and that don't work.

Comment: Ive done that ! thanks

Comment: Curiosity: what happens if you use /broaders/http ? Or /broaders/test%3A2F2F ?

Comment: @Gimby /http returns "http"; while /test%3A2F2F does not return anything. even /test% does not return anything.

Comment: So then you're a bit closer to the why, you can't use certain characters in the value. At this point I would dive into the API documentation and figure out what the restrictions are, and how to circumvent them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should pass the url as a parameter. Now, with the allow_encoded_slash you are generating urls that aren't broaders/XXXX but broaders/XXX/YYY/ZZZ so they don't match your regexp.

Comment: The variable K I pass in the PathParam is the URL!

Comment: That's the problem. a PathParam it's something embedded into the uri request, and a Param it's something you "add" to the uri request in order to generate the final url.
I mean:
http://www.blabla.com/xxx/parameter1 it's not the same as 
http://www.blabla.com/xxx?parameter1=yyy

If you need to send the url value, send it as a parameter, not as part or your request

Comment: Do you mean like using the Scanner to read the URL? that's really what I dont want to do. I need that URL to be part of the final URL..

Comment: Passing the url as a pathparam, you're changing your requesting url and you don't want this. You need to keep your url static and just send a value that will be processed after you select the processing method.

Edited:
Use "@RequestParam("url") String url" in your method instead of PathParam and, when you perform the http request, create the url correctly, like localhost/app/.../broaders/?url=YOUR_VALUE

Comment: Actually that is exactly what I am wondering how to do. How am I supposed to make it look like ?url=value?

Comment: In your java class, use this code:

String getBroader(@RequestParam("url") String url){
    return k;
 }

And, in your browser, type the following url:

localhost/app/.../broaders/test?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftematres.befdata.biow.uni-leipzig.de%2Fvocab%2F%3Ftema%3D254

Comment: Thank you @JavierV for the answer, however it did not solve it :( I will upgrade your comments though.

Comment: Using

`@GET
@Path("broaders/retrieveurl")
@produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@public String getBroader(@RequestParam("myurl") String myurl){
    return myurl;
}`

should do the trick. What happens when you publish this code and uses the following url from internet explorer/firefox/chrome?

localhost/app/.../broaders/retrieveurl?myurl=url_de_prueba

Pay attention to the @RequestParam and @Path annotations and values

Comment: Hey @JavierV. It actually worked with QueryParam instead of RequestParam ! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

A `@PathParam` does not include `/` by default.

Try a regular expression for the `@PathParam`.

```
@Path("broaders/{k:.+}")
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not change anything. I tried on both Path and on PathParam and on them both, but no chance.